# Excel copying different cell in same row, paste to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a workbook to copy a cell value to a worksheet if the value = "Yes", for instance, Column A contains times and Column's B to G have a drop down box for yes/no. If Cell B2 has Yes, then it'll copy the time to a different sheet from A2 to the next available row in Sheet4, Column C, also if G5 has "Yes" then it'll copy the time from A5 to the next available row in Sheet4, Column H

I've been experimenting with the below code, and I'm getting stuck. It only seems to be working if I have the "Overview" sheet selected and I can't seem to get it to move across, only down.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 4
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Overview")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    For i = 2 To N

        If ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Yes" Then
            ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Overview")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    N = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 4

    For Each cell In Range("B2:G" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)


        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            ws2.Range("A" & j).Value = ws1.Range("A" & cell.Row).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If


    Next cell

End Sub
```

It was working only if you had Overview sheet selected because you had set the value of N to be the count the number of rows in the activesheet rather than the `overview sheet(ws1)`. and it wasn't scanning all the columns as your code was written only for column `C`

Hope the above solves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get that one to work. I think I'll just make my code nice and messy and have 5 different macro's for each column and call one macro to run them in order until I can find a better solution.

Comment: Can you highlight the error you are getting. As i tested and it works fine for me.